# Cannot find resource named 'X', why not?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to create a wizard UI for inventories management. The relevant line in the xaml is:

```xml
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Current}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource inventorySelector}"/>
```

"Current" is the currently active view model, one of AvailableInventoriesViewModel, GroupsViewModel, NewArticlesViewModel, ResultViewModel. The DataTemplateSelector I have defined as such:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Centron.WPF.WarehousingExtension.InventoryModule.ViewModels.WizardViewModels;

namespace Centron.WPF.WarehousingExtension.InventoryModule.UI.DataTemplateSelectors
{
    public class InventoryDatatemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate AvailableDatatype { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate GroupsDatatype { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate NewDatatype { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ResultDatatype { get; set; }

        public InventoryDatatemplateSelector()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("");
        }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is AvailableInventoriesViewModel)
                return AvailableDatatype;
            else if (item is GroupsViewModel)
                return GroupsDatatype;
            else if (item is NewArticlesViewModel)
                return NewDatatype;
            else return ResultDatatype;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create instances of the DataTemplates and a Selector like this:

```xml
<base:InventoryViewBase.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:AvailableInventoriesViewModel" x:Key="availableInventoriesDatatype">
        <controls:AvailableInventoriesView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:GroupsViewModel" x:Key="groupsDatatype">
        <controls:GroupsView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:NewArticlesViewModel" x:Key="newArticlesDatatype">
        <controls:NewArticlesView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:ResultViewModel" x:Key="resultDatatype">
        <controls:ResultView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <selector:InventoryDatatemplateSelector
            x:Key="inventorySelector" 
            AvailableDatatype="{StaticResource availableInventoriesDatatype}"
            GroupsDatatype="{StaticResource groupsDatatype}"
            NewDatatype="{StaticResource newArticlesDatatype}"
            ResultDatatype="{StaticResource resultDatatype}"/>
</base:InventoryViewBase.Resources>
```

I set a breakpoint in the constructor of my InventoryDatatemplateSelector, and can step through it, but in the next Debug step, apparently when it tries to set the first property of that selector instance, I immediately get an exception with inner exception:

> Cannot find resource named \"availableInventoriesDatatype\". Resource names are case sensitive.

What's the deal, why is the resource not found when it's clearly defined?

Comment: There are a couple things you may not know that caused this issue.  First, xaml is (with very few exceptions) parsed from top to bottom and converted into an object graph.  That means **order is significant**.  Second, DataTemplates are designed so that they will assign themselves a Key based on their `DataType`, which (essentially) supplants the x:Key property.  So, if you want to define a DataTemplate with both a DataType (which is completely unnecessary as you use it) and an x:Key, you have to put the x:Key first.  Confusing, yes, but its as a result of making DTs easier to use.

Answer (score 30):

Ok, I found the solution. The only error was that the "Key" property of a resource has to be set first. So instead of:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:AvailableInventoriesViewModel" x:Key="availableInventoriesDatatype" >
        <controls:AvailableInventoriesView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

I need:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="availableInventoriesDatatype" DataType="viewModels:AvailableInventoriesViewModel" >
        <controls:AvailableInventoriesView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This is so dumb. I hate xaml, with a vengeance.

Comment: Xaml is awesome, your comment is invalid.  I'm not sure why your're even bothering using static resources when you could have defined them inline in your data template selector.  Also, how you're doing this is a bit odd.  Content controls will automatically search through resources for the first data template with a given type, so you could probably have foregone your selector, if each template is matched to a specific type

Comment: @Will I have tried it your way. I removed the Key property from my DataTemplates and used no selector on the ContentPresenter. Now all that is displayed in the ContentPresenter is Current.ToString(), not the actual control. It also happens if I put the DataTemplates in the ContentPresenter.Resources.

Comment: Switch from a ContentPresenter (usually used in a ContentControl template) to a ContentControl.

Comment: This does seem dumb. Attribute order is not significant in XML, as XAML is based on XML I would not expect attribute order to matter.

Comment: To me, XAML has the VB6 ring to it all over and I've done both extensively.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to show other readers at first glance that this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 10):

I know you found your problem, but there is a simpler way to solve this that I thought you should know about.  Since each of your DataTemplates are working on different classes, you don't really need to build your DataTemplateSelector to do this.  If you simply declare your DataTemplates without keys like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AvailableInventoriesViewModel}">
    <controls:AvailableInventoriesView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:GroupsViewModel}">
    <controls:GroupsView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:NewArticlesViewModel}">
    <controls:NewArticlesView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:ResultViewModel">
    <controls:ResultView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And declare your `ContentPresenter` without specifying the `ContentTemplateSelector` such as:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Current}" />
```

Then the appropriate DataTemplate will be selected for whatever Type `Current` is set to.

This is a much cleaner solution and eliminates the need for the custom selector.

WPF is powerful and very flexible but can be it can be challenging to get your head wrapped around it. But once you understand what it can do, I think that you will change your opinion on the matter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide the full basic code for assigning multiple DataTemplates to a single ContentPresenter? I have tried assigning multiple DataTemplates to the ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate property, but it can only be set once. This gives me an error:<ContentPresenter>
          <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="asd">
                  <TextBlock />
              </DataTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="asd">
                  <TextBlock />
              </DataTemplate>
          </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
      </ContentPresenter>

Comment: My point is that you don't need to assign any `DataTemplate` to your ContentPresenter.  If you leave the keys off of your `DataTemplate` declarations, then your `ContentPresenter` will use the `DataTemplate` that matches your `DataType` automagically.

Comment: I have tried it your way. I removed the Key property from my DataTemplates and used no selector on the ContentPresenter. Now all that is displayed in the ContentPresenter is Current.ToString(), not the actual control. It also happens if I put the DataTemplates in the ContentPresenter.Resources.

Comment: There must be something else screwing you up then because it works for me.  If you can't get it working then I would post another question asking what is wrong with your new code.  It will be hard to diagnose anything in the comments and it will not be helpful to future users that are having the same problem.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Please leave a comment when you down vote so the issue can be addressed.

Comment: I don't take too kindly asking for help, providing all I can, and then being told told that my comment is invalid, and how *odd* my approach is, when the code provided as an answer does not even work either. As I found out in the end, a correct DataTemplate has to look like this:         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AvailableInventoriesViewModel}" >
            <controls:AvailableInventoriesView />
        </DataTemplate> then it can be found in resources.

Comment: I never said your comment is invalid or how odd your approach was.  You need to re-read everything that was written and who wrote them.

Comment: Also you are correct that you need the x:Type on the DataType declarations.  I had just recently discovered that I didn't always need the x:Type syntax (apparently it doesn't work universally).  I checked my sample app and sure enough I was using x:Type and when I removed it it stopped working.  Sorry for the oversight.  I have fixed the example for future users.

Comment: After more than an hour of poking around in my xaml you saved my day. {x:Type my:Model} instead of my:Model. Oh my...

Comment: Another +1 for the `x:Type` syntax. On another note, stuff like this is why sane programming languages have type checking at compile time rather than simply not working at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

Here was my case - I declared ItemTemplate  before DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox Name="peopleListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}, XPath=Person}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nameItemTemplate}">
    </ListBox>

<Grid.Resources>
            <!-- Name item template -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="nameItemTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>          
</Grid.Resources>
```

Then I just change the order and put Grid.Resources before the Listbox like bellow, everything fine now!!!

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <!-- Name item template -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="nameItemTemplate">
            <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>          
    </Grid.Resources>

<ListBox Name="peopleListBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpenseDataSource}, XPath=Person}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nameItemTemplate}">
    </ListBox>
```

Is not XAML so stupid? :) :)

Comment: Order of operations is important in any non-compiled language, and XML is one such.

Answer (score 0):

I give more detail in case of styling nested components. In this example, MainWindowGrid contains UserControlGrid and PanelGrid.

The following code will not work.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XeerSoft.UX.Themes">
    <Thickness x:Key="PanelRowMargin">0,0,0,10</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="PanelPadding">10</Thickness>

    <Color x:Key="Primary">#005C9D</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Color x:Key="Accent">#E3672B</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Color x:Key="DarkGray">#777777</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkGrayBrush" Color="{StaticResource DarkGray}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Color x:Key="LightGray">#E4E4E4</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrayBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightGray}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Style x:Key="MainWindowGrid"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Grid}}"
           TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayBrush}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="GridPanel"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Grid}}"
           TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="UserControlPanel"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}"
           TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, if you swap the declaration sequence so the MainWindowGrid goes last, it will work. (Outer scope, goes last)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XeerSoft.UX.Themes">
    <Thickness x:Key="PanelRowMargin">0,0,0,10</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="PanelPadding">10</Thickness>

    <Color x:Key="Primary">#005C9D</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Color x:Key="Accent">#E3672B</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Color x:Key="DarkGray">#777777</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkGrayBrush" Color="{StaticResource DarkGray}"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Color x:Key="LightGray">#E4E4E4</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrayBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightGray}"></SolidColorBrush>


    <Style x:Key="GridPanel"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Grid}}"
           TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="UserControlPanel"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}"
           TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MainWindowGrid"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Grid}}"
           TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```